# Apt-get Error: apt-listchanges and debconf

Tags: debian, apt, debconf

I am repeatedly getting this message:

```
Setting up apt-listchanges (3.10) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmp.aulCeycFHm.aptlc/debconf-helper.py", line 6, in <module>
    import debconf
ImportError: No module named 'debconf'
dpkg: error processing package apt-listchanges (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt-listchanges
```

debconf

```
~$ dpkg --status debconf
Package: debconf
Status: install ok installed
Priority: required
Section: admin
Installed-Size: 558
Maintainer: Debconf Developers <debconf-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: all
Multi-Arch: foreign
Version: 1.5.60
Replaces: debconf-tiny
Provides: debconf-2.0
Pre-Depends: perl-base (>= 5.6.1-4)
Recommends: apt-utils (>= 0.5.1), debconf-i18n
Suggests: debconf-doc, debconf-utils, whiptail | dialog, libterm-readline-gnu-perl, libgtk2-perl (>= 1:1.130), libnet-ldap-perl, perl, libqtgui4-perl, libqtcore4-perl
Conflicts: apt (<< 0.3.12.1), cdebconf (<< 0.96), debconf-tiny, debconf-utils (<< 1.3.22), dialog (<< 0.9b-20020814-1), menu (<= 2.1.3-1), whiptail (<< 0.51.4-11), whiptail-utf8 (<= 0.50.17-13)
Conffiles:
 /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf 7e9d09d5801a42b4926b736b8eeabb73
 /etc/debconf.conf 8c0619be413824f1fc7698cee0f23811
Description: Debian configuration management system
 Debconf is a configuration management system for debian packages. Packages
 use Debconf to ask questions when they are installed.
```

ls -l /usr/lib/python*/dist-packages/debconf.py

```
ls -l /usr/lib/python*/dist-packages/debconf.py
```

Comment: Have you successfully used apt-listchanges before? Have you configured or reconfigured it? Look at http://jxf.me/entries/better-apt-ubuntu/ --- scroll down to: Using apt-listchanges

Comment: Please add the output of the `dpkg --status debconf` and `ls -l /usr/lib/python*/dist-packages/debconf.py` commands to your question.

Comment: Do you have 'debconf' & 'debconf-utils' installed?

Comment: I have added the printouts from those commands. I have debconf and I now have debconf-utils.

Answer (score 4):

This may not be important to you anymore, but I figured out a workaround, at least for me.

The problem is that it can't find `debconf.py` on your path. In my case it was using a different python with different settings than what was normally on my path.

I eventually found a debconf.py file in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debconf.py`. For me, it was `python3.6` that had the wrong path, which you can find by doing:

```
$ python3.6
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

Which showed me that it didn't have what was on my `$PATH`. Rather than muck around too much, I just ran this:

```
# ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/debconf.py /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

The destination can be *anywhere* that shows up in that `sys.path`. You could probably copy instead of symlink. Regardless, That's what I did and it worked for me - I hope you have similar luck!

Answer (score 1):

I started getting this error when I upgraded my computation server from Debian `jessie` to Debian `stretch`.

My problem was that I had (foolishly) manually installed Python 3.5 system-wide before the upgrade to `stretch`, and that version of Python was 'masking' the default `stretch` Python 3 install. In particular, these factors were at play:

- My manual v3.5 install had put its `python3` symlink into `/usr/local/bin`
- The Debian `python3` system package had installed symlinks into `/usr/bin`
- `/usr/local/bin` was earlier in my `$PATH` than was `/usr/bin`

So, to fix this specific problem, all I had to do was rename the `/usr/local/bin/python3` symlink to, e.g., `/usr/local/bin/python3-local`, and then `import debconf` worked fine after a `python3` invocation.

A more complete solution would probably be a total uninstall of the system-wide manual version of Python 3.5, and re-installing it sandboxed.